# Javascript UI Dialog does not open first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

I am trying to use the jQuery UI Dialog. But it will not open first time. Consider:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
      <script src="dialog.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <p>Hello</p>
      <div id="dialog" title="Alert" style="display: none;"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

where `dialog.js` is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    showAlert("1");
    showAlert("2");
});

function showAlert(str) {
    $( "#dialog" ).html(str);
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
        modal: true,
        title: "Alert",
        buttons: {
            "OK": function() {
                document.getElementById("submit").value="Submit";
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This will only show the second dialog, the first dialog (with text "1") seems to be simply ignored..

See also [jQuery UI Dialog - Won't open the first time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111637/jquery-ui-dialog-wont-open-the-first-time).

Comment: The second one is replacing the contents of the `#dialog`. If you want to wait for the dialog to be closed, you have to put that in the `onClose` option.

Comment: @Barmar Of course, this was a silly question. I was trying to isolate the problem from a larger code. Now, the larger code seems similar to this, but there is no second dialog there, only the first one.. But still, the dialog does not open. But if I put a javascript `alert()` in front of it, it will open. Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like your script is going into a loop, so it never returns to the main event loop.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for the help! I think I have isolated the problem better now. I think I will post a new question. Should I delete this question?

Comment: Yeah, deleting this would be good. I've answered your other question.